# bootstrap3 - caret reverse on click in navbar-nav

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3, and I found few lines of css, that work great, making the caret to reverse (upside-down) on click.

```
.navbar-nav .open > a > b.caret {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
}
```

For your reference, this is my (pretty standard) dropdown:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Some Title Text <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Some Submenu text</li>
      <li>Some Submenu text</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Why is this happening? I would like your help to deeply understand it.
Thank you!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/
http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lotjh

Comment: nice trick! but I'm not sure it's the same approach used by Bootstrap and the code I posted. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is the same tecnhique. `caret` class in Bootstrap has 3 borders and 2 of them are transparent like in this example. Your code only overwrites `border-top` value and add `border-bottom` to change the direction of caret.

Comment: awesome, now everything's clear, thank you. If you care about points on stackoverflow you can add your answer and I will flag it as the appropriate one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap [`caret`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-carets) uses a popular trick to draw triangle in CSS.

You can see it [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lotjh)

CSS code for top and bottom arrows (triangles):

```
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}
```